# Limitations of beforeRouteLeave?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js with vue-router, and have a question about the 'beforeRouteLeave' navigation guard. I am using it for dirty-checking of a product object in my ProductDetail component, when the user clicks the Cancel button (so I can put up a confirmation dialog if there are unsaved changes). It works fine as long as the user clicks the Cancel button, which changes the route to '/product/list' (from '/product/detail'). If, however, the user directly enters '/product/list' in the browser's address bar, it's not called. This is a minor nuisance rather than a show-stopper, but I'm just wondering if there's some way I can get around this and get it to behave the same way as a link or button click?

FURTHER CLARIFICATION, AS REQUESTED:
In the component in question, clicking the Cancel button calls `this.$router.push({name:'product-list'})`, which is defined in the router config with the path '/product/list'. When this happens, the guard 'beforeRouteLeave' is successfully called before the route is changed. If, however, the user directly enters '/product/list' into the address bar, and changes the route that way, 'beforeRouteLeave' for my component is bypassed.

Comment: Could you explain issue a bit more - when user directly visit `/product/list`, the data are not rendered ? Does those data depends on something another ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.onbeforeunload` https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/578/ if you want to prevent leaving a link without saving changes.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return "Are you sure you want to close the window?";
}
```